# The closure of the union of a countable disjointed family of metric balls is the union of the closures

Tags: general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$ and $ \{r_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq (0,+\infty)$ sequences such that

$\overline{B(x_n,r_n)}\cap\overline{B(x_m,r_m)}=\emptyset$ for $m, n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $m\ne n$.

**My question is the following one**: is the equality

$\overline{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B(x_n,r_n)}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\overline{B(x_n,r_n)}$

true? If it's, true how can I prove it? If it's false, it would be true if I suppose that $X$ is separable?

Can anyone help me please?

*Proof Attempt.* Clearly

$\overline{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B(x_n,r_n)}\supseteq\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\overline{B(x_n,r_n)}$.

The problem is to show the remaining inclusion, i.e.

$\overline{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B(x_n,r_n)}\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\overline{B(x_n,r_n)}$.

Comment: I suggest (now that you have answers) that you prove that if $X$ has an accumulation point, this theorem is false.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace, I don’t think that that’s true (assuming that by theorem you mean the equality).

Comment: @CarstenS I'll admit this is only with intuition but for a metric space admitting an accumulation point, I'm pretty sure I can construct a sequence of balls for which the equality is not verified

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace, ah, okay, with quantifiers in that order I do not know. But I think that there is a metric space and sequences as in the question such that $(x_n)$ has an accumulation point and still equality holds. I was thinking of $\mathbb R^2$ with the SNCF metric and Paris as the accumulation point .

Comment: @CarstenS I see why you think of this, however I believe my thing works, I consider $(x_n)_n$ that converges to $x$, it forms a discrete set (without the $x$ of course) then take $r_n =\min \left( \inf_{m\in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{n\}} d(x_n,x_m), d(x_n,x) \right)/3$ I think it works even with SNCF distance. Don't hesitate to point out my mistakes :) I have an idea for Hausdorff spaces in general, but I need the countable choice axiom

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace, yes, I wasn’t sure what what your claim was. I agree that if you have a sequence $(x_n)$ without duplicate elements that converges to a point not in the sequence then you can always find a sequence $(r_n)$ that yields a counter-example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is false, we have a good counterexample in $\mathbb{R}$ (but you can easily generalize it to any normed space) given by $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and
$r_n = \min \left(\left| \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n-1} \right| ,\left| \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right| \right)/3 = \frac{1}{3n(n+1)}$.

We have
$$0 \notin  \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} \overline{B(x_n,r_n)}$$
But since $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \, \frac{1}{n} \in B(x_n,r_n)$,
$$0 \in  \overline{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} B(x_n,r_n)}$$

Comment: What is N* ?  Furthermore, It is the number 0 that either is or is not an element of the relevant set, not {0}.

Comment: $\mathbb{N}^*$ is $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$.   Of course it was $0$, not $\{0\}$, it’s a small typo that does’t really impact the comprehension of the counterexample.

Answer (score 6):

In $\mathbb R$, let $x_n=1/n$ and $r_n=1/(100n^2)$. Then $0$ is in the closure of the union  but not the union of the  closures

Comment: They are not all disjoint in your example

Comment: Change $n$ to $n^{100}$

Comment: Thanks, @JulesBesson; I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The two examples given above are great, but a more "high-level" intuition is that the LHS is a *closed* set, and the RHS is a *countable union of closed sets*, which is not necessarily closed. Therefore, every countable union of closed balls which is not closed (as the examples given above) will be a counter-example. "Covering" an open domain in the line\plane\space with closed balls is an intuitive example.

Comment: Be careful to stick to the conditions of non overlapping balls. You can't give a general construction since it is true for some metric sets. I think the author knew about infinite union already, but this is an countable union of disjoint closed balls so for some odd reason it could have worked (but unfortunately not haha)

Comment: I understand that this is not the general case in the sense of countable unions, but in my intuition, I can cover any "nice" domain (in the plane\space) with closed balls\spheres. I think it's pretty much straight forward, at least intuitively.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my comment if you have a metric space, this is equivalent to having an accumulation point in your set. If not the identity is verified.